# Window title is not changed after pdf is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension which changes the title of some pdf page, for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.01463v2.pdf.

The code works fine *before* the pdf is loaded, but when the pdf is fully loaded the window's title is changed back to the pdf name (instead of my title) and using `document.title = "cool title"` or Chrome messages to `background.js` does not work.

However doing a manual `document.title = "cool title"` from the console in a given pdf page works well.

```
// content_script.js
const makeTitle = (time) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        title = "cool title"
        console.log("Updating pdf title");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "update-title", options: { title } })
        window.document.title = title;
    }, time)
}

makeTitle(0)
makeTitle(1 * 1000);
makeTitle(5 * 1000);
makeTitle(10 * 1000);
makeTitle(20 * 1000);
makeTitle(60 * 1000);
makeTitle(5 * 60 * 1000);
```

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Executing background message")
    if (request.type == "update-title") {
        const { title } = request.options;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, { code: `document.title = "${title}"` });
    }
});
```

I have to use those `setTimeout` because I cannot detect if a pdf is done loading. `makeTitle` works fine before the pdf is loaded, but not after and I'd like to solve this. Thanks!

PS: I know there's a duplicate title change, it's just none of those 2 strategies work

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated in background.js and when changeInfo contains new `title`, call executeScript. Alternatively, use MutationObserver in the content script to observe changes to document.querySelector('title') element.

Comment: I'll try but do you have any idea why **setting** the title does not work in what I've tried?

Comment: Because the pdf viewer sets it after the document is loaded, of course.

Comment: That's not the point, if you read my question carefully you'll see there are title setters *after* the doc is loaded and that's the whole point of the question :) (setTimeout)

Comment: I only intended to make one comment because it's a trivial problem and the solution is also trivial. Did you try it already?

Comment: It is not trivial otherwise the solutions I have already tried would have worked @wOxxOm also if it's so trivial can you explain why my setters don't work even though they are triggered at the right moments? Also I tried your suggestions and still, the setting is the issue, even catching the right event, when onUpdated is triggered after the pdf loads and the title changes. FYI in the OnUpdated listened the setter is `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code: \`document.title = "${title}"\` });` (as in my question)

Comment: onUpdated listener*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Chrome. It sets the title internally and ignores DOM `title` element.

The workaround is to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated to set an empty title, then set the intended one.

background.js

```js
const title = 'foo';
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (info.title && info.title !== title && tab.url.endsWith('.pdf')) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: `document.title=''; document.title="${title}"`,
      runAt: 'document_start',
      // runs immediately if this change occurs before DOMContentLoaded
    });
  }
});
```

There's another bug in Chrome: it shows the built-in title intermittently when you switch to another tab and back. This particular bug seems to be fixed in the upcoming "unseasoned" PDF viewer, which can be enabled currently via `chrome://flags/#pdf-unseasoned`

Comment: That helped me solve the setter issue. So it was *not* trivial ;) Thanks a lot for your investigation

Comment: Just to be clear, this will trigger an infinite update loop no? of course what's inside the if ill not be triggered more than once but still the event listener will be called (twice actually because of the 2 setters in `code`). Can this cause performance issues in your opinion?

Comment: The listener will work until you unregister it so indeed it's infinite. To prevent self-recursion there's a check for `info.title !== title`. Since it's a trivial operation I don't see any performance issues but if you're concerned you can use chrome://tracing or other low-level performance tools.

Comment: In case you meant a loop like `while(true){}` then I did not observe such behavior in my tests.

Comment: No I did mean an infinite loop of event -> update title -> event etc.

Comment: Of course, this is what happens as long as the listener is registered but as the answer describes the changes occur only in certain cases, not constantly.

Comment: In case you were worried that Chrome reacts to this code and resets the title automatically, it doesn't.